# Calling a function of an object instance using embedded Python

Tags: python, c++, c++11, boost

I want to be able to run Python scripts in my app to allow automating stuff and modifying existing objects/calling methods of existing objects.

In my application there is a `BasicWindow` class and `MainWindow` class that derives from the former. For now at application start I initialize one instance of `MainWindow`. This object has many functions, among them there is one that loads files (`LoadFile()`), and I will use it as example here.

Lets say that I want to call that particular function (but not limited to that function, it is just an example of the functionality that I want to achieve from Python) of that particular object instance.

This method is not a static one. For this I am using **Boost.Python** and I am creating a module this way:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(MyModule)
{

    MainWindow::PythonExpose(); //not really sure how to operate here
    //more stuff
}
```

The idea is that I could call from Python something like:

```
MainWindow.LoadFile()
```

or even better, just:

```
LoadFile()
```

One solution could be to create static, application scoped functions and then just expose those functions. In C++ I could find the particular instance of `MainWindow`: (both methods are static)

```
void AppHelper::LoadFile()
{
    GetMainWindow()->LoadFile();
}


void AppHelper::PythonExposeGlobal()
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("LoadFile", &AppHelper::LoadFile);
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this? The general question would be: is it possible to call methods of existing objects (in C++) from Python? If so, how to do it? If not, what can I do to mimic this behavior?

For example, I could easily enable scripting capabilities in my C# application and sharing instances of existing objects. (But of course C# has reflection).

Comment: Yes, either the way you propose, or you expose the class (no constructor, just the functions you need), create a python object referring to existing instance (using a pointer -- e.g. `bp::object(bp::ptr(&foo))`) and then push that to the interpreter so your scripts can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the object will live as long as any scripts using it run, then there's a fairly simple approach that I use.

I'll use a primitive counter class for demonstration:

```
class counter
{
public:
    counter() : count(0) {}

    void increment() { ++count; }

    int count;
};
```

Now, I expose this class to python, such that it considers it non-copyable, and doesn't allow construction of new instances. I also expose any members that I want to use from the scripts.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
    bp::class_<counter, boost::noncopyable>("Counter", bp::no_init)
        .def("increment", &counter::increment)
        ;
}
```

Next step is to create a Python object that uses an existing instance, and allow the script to use it (e.g. add it as an attribute of some module, such as the main one).

```
counter c;

bp::object main_module(bp::import("__main__"));

main_module.attr("c") = bp::object(bp::ptr(&c));
```

Now your scripts can use this instance:

```
c.increment()
```

---

Sample program:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bp = boost::python;

// Simple counter that can be incremented
class counter
{
public:
    counter() : count(0) {}

    void increment() { ++count; }

    int count;
};

// Expose the counter class to Python
// We don't need constructor, since we only intend to use instance
// already existing on the C++ side
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
    bp::class_<counter, boost::noncopyable>("Counter", bp::no_init)
        .def("increment", &counter::increment)
        ;
}

int main()
{
    Py_InitializeEx(0);

    // Bind our class
    initexample();

    counter c;

    bp::object main_module(bp::import("__main__"));
    bp::object main_namespace(main_module.attr("__dict__"));

    // Add the current instance of counter to Python as attribute c of the main module
    main_module.attr("c") = bp::object(bp::ptr(&c));

    std::cout << "Before: " <<  c.count << '\n';

    // Increment the counter from Python side
    bp::exec("c.increment()", main_namespace);

    std::cout << "After: " << c.count << '\n';

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Console Output:

```
Before: 0
After: 1
```